# JSS, is there a way to create custom types?

Tags: jss

I am totally new to Sitecore, and a front-end developer, so please bear with me.

I'm on a project that is prototyped using JSS and for some of our components we'd like to define custom types like: "align" that would be one of ["top", "middle", "bottom"] but the allowed, predefined, types (as in SingleLineText or RichText for examples) are limited.

Is there a way to define such lists as "types"?

Also, is it possible to define custom types like type: { some, other, fields } and later reuse those as { name: "foo", type: "MyCustomType" } ?

I've checked the JSS documentation but so far it's pretty unclear if this is possible; any pointers is good.

Answer (score 5):

In Sitecore such a list would be implemented via a *droplink* field (in JSS manifest this is referred to as *ContentLink*).

Essentially you'd make a folder in `data/content` to store your list items, such as `/data/content/alignments/{top|middle|bottom}/en.yml`. Give each of those an `id`, i.e. `id:align-top`.

Then on your component instance (on a route) where you'd like to refer to an alignment, add a `ContentLink` field, and set the value to an ID reference to the alignment item's ID:

```
myAlignmentField:
    id: align-top
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot.

If I get it correctly, ContentLink is actually "a link to data/content". How do you actually point, refer, to the list? I see that you create alignments in data/content, you refer in a route with "myAlignmentField"… but I don't see how you actually say that "this alignment list is taking values from the alignments directory"

Let say I define the component like this: 
  ***{ name: "alignments", type: ContentLink }***

How do I link alignments to this so the contributor have a list of some fields to choose from?

Comment: The source of the content link can be set in the manifest as well using the [`source` attribute](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/0292a05077c4ef21b668eb9c30412f57620c3779/samples/react/sitecore/definitions/components/Styleguide-FieldUsage-ItemLink.sitecore.js#L22) to specify the Sitecore path to retrieve items to list.

Comment: ok will fiddle with that, thanks a lot again!